# Pandas: Merge dataframes with repeated indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to merge two datasets that share a common index. In my real data, this index is a serial number and it is repeated. The serial number corresponds to a vehicle and it is repeated for every trip taken with that vehicle. So there are different feature values depending on the trip circumstances.

Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=["a", "a", "b", "b"],
)

df1

>>
    A   B   C   D
a   A0  B0  C0  D0
a   A1  B1  C1  D1
b   A2  B2  C2  D2
b   A3  B3  C3  D3


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A2": ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
        "B2": ["B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"],
        "C2": ["C4", "C5", "C6", "C7"],
        "D2": ["D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"],
    },
    index=["a", "b", "b", "b"],
)
​
df2

>>
    A2  B2  C2  D2
a   A4  B4  C4  D4
b   A5  B5  C5  D5
b   A6  B6  C6  D6
b   A7  B7  C7  D7
```

I am struggling to see the best way of emerging these two datasets. Apart from the index, they don't share more common information. So I'd like to use as much as I can from the two but also avoid unnecessary repetition.

I attempted:

```
df1.join(df2)

>>
    A   B   C   D   A2  B2  C2  D2
a   A0  B0  C0  D0  A4  B4  C4  D4
a   A1  B1  C1  D1  A4  B4  C4  D4
b   A2  B2  C2  D2  A5  B5  C5  D5
b   A2  B2  C2  D2  A6  B6  C6  D6
b   A2  B2  C2  D2  A7  B7  C7  D7
b   A3  B3  C3  D3  A5  B5  C5  D5
b   A3  B3  C3  D3  A6  B6  C6  D6
b   A3  B3  C3  D3  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

but as you can see for every df1 I'm adding all rows of df2 to each one of the rows of df1... This is not wrong I think... but considering the size of my datasets (3GB)it would end up creating more observations than necessary... So I would like to avoid this if possible.

I also attempted:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")
```

but as I have repeated indexes of serial numbers it returns an error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

**What's the best way of merging these two datasets of repeated indexes? In other words, what the best output should be in order to preserve information from both datasets and minimise repetition (affects data size significantly)?**

Comment: Can you show the right output you are looking for? Did this give you what you are looking for? `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: I'm asking exactly that. What the best way of doing it would be from your experiences. And that gives the same error I listed above as there are repeated indexes' values.

Comment: what is your expected output from that?

Comment: Like I commented above that is exactly what I'm asking. I edited the question to make it clearer. The way I managed to get it ends up too repetitive and perhaps extremely unnecessary and computational demanding...

Comment: what is your expected output from that?...like you posted the df's also post the expected output from that df's to make it more clear **:)**

Comment: Please refer to the edited question. That is exactly what I'm asking. What output would be the best to keep all the information and avoid repetition?

Comment: I think it depends on your business case on how you want to "deduplicate" the data before merging/concatenation.  You could pre-aggregate the values first. Something like `df1 = df1.groupby("_index").agg("&".join)` after first naming the index "_index".